# How to prepare the HTML for Wordpress

Tags: theme-development, html

Right now I'm finishing a design in Photoshop and I'm about to turn it to HTML. After that I'm want to turn it into a Wordpress theme using Underscores starter theme.
How can I prepare the HTML so the transition to _s would be smooth and easy without changing a lot of HTML and CSS in order it to fit?

Comment: https://html5boilerplate.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and easiest solution (imo) would be to develop your design directly in the Underscore theme. This way you will code only once the design - you won't have to redo the dynamic parts (like the menu items, widgets and other parts managed by Wordpress).

The alternative would be to code your design in plain HTML/CSS/JS and then transform these files in a WordPress theme. But I don't see this solution to be efficient / productive.

Comment: Is there any striped down version of _s without all the php and only with the HTML?

Comment: No, there's not, since Underscore *is* a starter WP-theme, there's no point in having a 'theme' without the specific code that actually makes it a WP-theme.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific thing, but here are some tips to make it smoother:

1. Style.css - make sure it in root folder and not inside style folder, as wordpress style will be in root and if html one is not in root, once you copy it to wordpress, you would need to update image links in it.
2. header/footer, make sure that repeatable part (header / footer) will remain same on all html pages.
3. Make sure html is working 100% correct, its easier to change it in html, altho not case every time, for example footer/header is easier to change in wp because you have one file to change, and in html you need to do that for each html page.

Will update if i figure something else. But first 2 are most important ones. Yes, first one you can skip by calling css from style folder and having clean root one, but keeping style in root will allow you later to easily edit it from wp editor.